# Problems about python closure:why does the code keep the value of local variable in a function?

Tags: python

In my idea,inside a closure we can reference variable beyond its own scope.But there's something I can't understand in the following code:

```
def counter(start_at=0) :
    count = [start_at]
    def incr():
        count[0] += 1
        return count[0]
    return incr

count = counter(5)
print count() # 6
print count() # 7
count2 = counter(100)
print count2() # 101
print count() # 8
```

It seems like that inside the function 'counter',local variable 'count' is never destroyed,And I can run count() again and again to increase the previous value count[0].
What's special for closure in this case? What does the interpreter do to manage and recycle the resources of the function containing a closure? 
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Closures are dereferenced at the time you use them. To facilitate this, closures stay around for the duration of the function referencing them, yes.

Calling `counter()` *again* will create a new closure, as a new `incr()` function object is produced that is independent from other such functions produced by other calls to `counter()`.

You can see the closure cells referenced on the returned object:

```
>>> incr = counter(10)
>>> incr.func_closure
(<cell at 0x102ebec20: list object at 0x10570f098>,)
>>> incr.func_closure[0]
<cell at 0x102ebec20: list object at 0x10570f098>
>>> incr.func_closure[0].cell_contents
[10]
```

It is these cells that keep the original variable reference from `counter()` to the `count` list alive.